# "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" while creating unique index

Tags: mysql, mariadb, foreign-keys

I was attempted to execute following queries:

```
CREATE TABLE `lob_sections` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `section_name` varchar(600) NOT NULL,
 `lob_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `agency_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `display_order` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
 `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
 `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 `last_modified_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `unq_lob_sections` (`agency_id`,`lob_type`,`section_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `lob_custom_fields` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `field_label` varchar(1400) NOT NULL,
 `field_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
 `display_order` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
 `required` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 `last_modified_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT unq_section_field_label UNIQUE (section_id, field_label),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_section_id` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `lob_sections` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

lob_sections table is created successfully, but lob_custom_fields is not creating, it is throwing me following error:

> #1005 - Can't create table `abc_db`.`lob_custom_fields` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

When I click on Details, then it shows me reason "`Create  table` abc_db`.`lob_custom_fields`with foreign key`fk_section_id `constraint failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns.------------`".

If I remove the line "`CONSTRAINT unq_section_field_label UNIQUE (section_id, field_label),`" from create table statement of lob_custom_fields table, then it created successfully.

How to add unique index in lob_custom_fields table? Create-Alter both are showing same error when I attempt to add unique index. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I removed my answer which was wrong. The primary key is already set in the request. If you saw it, don't take it in account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says

> Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes

> The InnoDB internal maximum key length is 3500 bytes, but MySQL itself restricts this to 3072 bytes. This limit applies to the length of the combined index key in a multi-column index.

that is for mysql 8

so you must define

`field_label` varchar(1022)

That fits

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `lob_sections` (
>  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>  `section_name` varchar(600) NOT NULL,
>  `lob_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
>  `agency_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
>  `display_order` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
>  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
>  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
>  `last_modified_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
>  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>  UNIQUE KEY `unq_lob_sections` (`agency_id`,`lob_type`,`section_name`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `lob_custom_fields` (
>  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>  `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>  `field_label` varchar(1022) NOT NULL,
>  `field_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
>  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
>  `display_order` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
>  `required` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
>  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
>  `last_modified_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
>  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>  CONSTRAINT unq_section_field_label UNIQUE (section_id, field_label),
>  CONSTRAINT `fk_section_id` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `lob_sections` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d00fc32b3d06166510c4b65d60666f71)*

Comment: You are amazing. Thanks a lot. Size is making difference.